# Uncaught Error: INVALID_CHARACTER_ERR: DOM Exception 5

Tags: javascript, unicode, base64

```
$('form#update').submit(function(){
    var _data = $(this).serializeArray();
    var param = {};
    $.map(_data,function(a,b){
        if(a.name=='HotelName'){
            param[a.name] = window.btoa(a.value);
        }
        else{
            param[a.name] = a.value;
        }
    });
    console.log(param);
    $.post('api.coupon_edit_post.php',param,function(r){
        coupons();
        reloadMarkers();
    });
    return false;
});
```

Is window.btoa causing this error?

I'm using window.btoa so I can pass most of the characters.

**EDIT:** I tried the [MDN solution](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.btoa#Unicode_Strings) but it's not working. I am using Google Chrome Version 24.0.1312.57 m

Comment: In which line did this error occur and on which browser?

Comment: @w4rumy no line log indicated. I'm just using GC console.

Comment: The way to decide whether `window.btoa` causes this is to create a test case with just the call to `window.btoa` and the piece of data contained in `a.value`.

Comment: Enable `Pause on uncaught exceptions` in the Chrome debugger.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario What did you edit on my question? I see nothing. Regarding your advice. I think it so because when I removed that line, it's fine.

Comment: I expanded the `GC` acronym to *Google Chrome*. I didn't feel it was the most commonly accepted usage for it.

Comment: Please take a closer look to my answer and TRY it. Then give me feedback if it worked.

Answer (score 6):

The Error comes definitely from `window.btoa`.

You should **modify** the MDN solution and omit the decoding step before the conversion, like following:

```
function utf8_to_b64( str ) {
    return window.btoa(encodeURIComponent( str ));
}

function b64_to_utf8( str ) {
    return decodeURIComponent(window.atob( str ));
}
```

This creates the b64 string from the encoded string instead of decoding it again (which again would create symbols, `btoa` can't process). Now this works:

```
utf8_to_b64('✓ à la mode');
b64_to_utf8("JUUyJTlDJTkzJTIwJUMzJUEwJTIwbGElMjBtb2Rl");
```

of course due to the encoding this significantly lengthens the b64 string.

You can now modify your example:

```
param[a.name] = utf8_to_b64(a.value);
```

Comment: Did you visit the link I posted?

Comment: Ok. absolutely not this answer.

Comment: **Christoph** Yes, I mention it in my question. Please see the link. THe answer you posted is what on the link.

Comment: @MarCejas well, before yelling at other people you should take a closer look, read *thoroughly* and try out what these people posted. Then you would notice, that my functions differ from those on MDN like I clearly explained.

Comment: same exception. Uncaught Error: INVALID_CHARACTER_ERR: DOM Exception 5

Comment: Can you please post some example strings? This error should not occur on encoded strings.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24375/discussion-between-mar-cejas-and-christoph)